# valid html - '<' or '>' in between <script>tags

Tags: javascript, html, validation, xhtml

When I use the html validator:

http://validator.w3.org/

It gives me an error. In the header of my page, I have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#countdown').countdown({
        until: '+2d+3h+1m+6s',
        layout: '{d<}{dn} {dl}, {d>}{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}'
    });
});
</script>
```

The part within `layout` that is given a string contains a `<`. The validator is giving an error.

Do I just discount this, since it's part of a script tag? Is it something with the validator?

I know some might suggest putting it in an external file, but it's dynamic and I don't want to figure that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrap it with CDATA

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#countdown').countdown({
        until: '+2d+3h+1m+6s',
        layout: '{d<}{dn} {dl}, {d>}{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}'
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the HTML 4 Recommendation's note about specifying non-HTML data in element content, end tags are recognized within SCRIPT elements, but other kinds of markup --such as start tags and comments--are not. This is an unintuitive quirk of SGML for elements defined to have CDATA content.

Try

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#countdown').countdown({
        until: '+2d+3h+1m+6s',
        layout: '{d<}{dn} {dl}, {d\>}{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't match up with the error that Matthew is reporting (which suggests that XHTML is being used so the rules for HTML don't apply as script elements don't have intrinsic CDATA)